# Arquillian Spring Tomcat 7 embedded - mock @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss-arquillian

I'm working on a multi-module maven project, and I'm trying to integrate arquillian in it to ease development and create some integration tests.
I'm using Tomcat 7 embedded, and I got to a point where everything works.
Now I want one of the classes that are injected in a service to be mocked. When I'm debugging (using Intellij Idea) everything seems to be working nice... my test @Configuration class (ApplicationConfig2) is added to the WAR, it injects a Dummy object which is later used by the service.
The problem is when running the same test using maven (clean install) (surefire plugin) it tells me an error occurred.
Here's my deployment:

```
@Deployment(testable = false)
public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
    File[] files = Maven.resolver()
            .offline()
            .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
            .resolve("org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.6",
                    "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.3.1"
            )
            .withTransitivity()
            .asFile();

    return ShrinkWrap
            .create(WebArchive.class, "ROOT.war")
            .addClass(Controller.class)
            .addClass(Service.class)
            .addClass(SomeObjectInterface.class)
            .addClass(MockedSomeObjectImpl.class)
            .addClass(MyApplication2.class)
            .addClass(ApplicationConfig2.class)
            .addClass(MyWebAppInitializer2.class)
            .addAsLibraries(files)
            .setWebXML("in-container-web.xml");
}
```

Here's my web app initializer used in tests:

```
@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class MyWebAppInitializer2 implements WebApplicationInitializer {...}
```

I have another one named MyWebAppInitializer which is used by the "real" WAR module.

The error that I get is :

```
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [foo.MyWebAppInitializer@1e194cf1, foo.MyWebAppInitializer2@f0a71a7, org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer@76ab92a7]
Aug 11, 2015 4:50:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

So, for some reason, even if I don't include the class MyWebAppInitializer in the web archive, it seems it is loaded by Tomcat even the same. I'm checking the generated WAR package, and the only class present is MyWebAppInitializer2 (the testing one), and not MyWebAppInitializer.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but maybe this helps understanding the error: The embedded Tomcat server is started as part of the project containing the test class. This also means that your original `MyWebAppInitializer` is in the classpath, and used during Tomcat startup. Ideally an embedded Tomcat would be started in an empty environment, and filled only based on your Arquillian configuration. Sadly, I have no idea how this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found out... nobody should use the embedded containers, as they are unreliable.

Comment: That neither is an answer to your question, nor helpful.